# Application name in URL instead application ID

Tags: facebook, url

How can I get application name in format http://apps.facebook.com/MySuperUniqueAppName instead of http://apps.facebook.com/123456789 ? I defined application name while creating on MySuperUniqueAppName but I still get numbers. Is there something like limit, that there must be some people use it or like it to change application name in it's URL?

Comment: IMHO, SuperApplicationName is better than 84975380947530495 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the developer app make sure you have an App Namespace defined, then set up your callback in the 'App on Facebook' section, your app should then be accessible at apps.facebook.com/{app namespace}

Comment: Defining namespace is completely enough :). Thank you very much. I need to ask, because I'm confused if is it OK: Canvas URL contain URL of localisation of application on my server (http://my.server.domain/ and https://my.server.domain/)? If I define return_uri should I use this URL or http://apps.facebook.com/mysuperapplication?

Comment: In most cases i think you'll want to direct users to `apps.facebook.com/yourapp` after login, but i think both will work (I.e you can direct either to the app on Facebook or directly to your server)